# Characterisations of second order PDEs by changing the variables.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> #### Question
>
> If a second order PDE is defined as
>
> a(x, y) u<sub>xx</sub> + 2b(x, y) u<sub>xy</sub> + c(x, y)u<sub>yy</sub> = d(x, y, u, u<sub>x</sub>, u<sub>y</sub>)
>
> and the variables are defined as
>
> x, y -> ξ(x,y), η(x,y)
>
> and the transformation is non-singular, how do you show that
>
> u<sub>x</sub> = u<sub>ξ</sub>ξ<sub>x</sub> + u<sub>η</sub>η<sub>x</sub>
>
> and
>
> u<sub>xx</sub> = (u<sub>ξξ</sub> ξ<sub>x</sub> + u<sub>ξη</sub> η<sub>x</sub>)ξ<sub>x</sub> + u<sub>ξ</sub> ξ<sub>xx</sub> + (u<sub>ηξ</sub> ξ<sub>x</sub> + u<sub>ηη</sub> η<sub>x</sub>)η<sub>x</sub> + u<sub>η</sub> η<sub>xx</sub>?

I feel like I'm missing something obvious but I just can't seem to wrap my head around how to differentiate ξ and η.

Comment: @doraemonpaul: When doing a massive retagging, please try to edit only a limited amount of questions at a time, say 5 to 10 questions in a day and the rest over subsequent days. Right now the front page is flooded with old PDE questions, and other new questions will not get enough attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just the chain rule.

In the new variables, $u$ is a function of $\xi$ and $\eta$, which depend on $x$ and $y$:

$$\begin{matrix}
 & & u & & \\
 & /&  & \backslash \\
 & \xi & & \eta\\
/ & \backslash & & / & \backslash \\
x & y & & x & y
\end{matrix}$$

Then the chain rule for functions of several variables gives
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial \xi}\frac{\partial\xi}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial \eta}\frac{\partial\eta}{\partial x}.
$$
Similarly for the derivative with respect to $y$. To find the second derivatives you keep using the chain rule and the product rule.